# Using a created extension method

Tags: c#, view, extension-methods

Here's the method I created:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using MvcApplication1.Models;
using System.Text;

namespace MvcApplication1.HelperMethods
{
    public static class NavigationalMenu
    {
        public static string MyMenu(this HtmlHelper helper)
        {
            ProyectoFinalEntities x = new ProyectoFinalEntities();
            var categories = x.Categories;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (Category c in categories)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(helper.RouteLink(c.Name, "AuctionCategoryDetails", new { categoryName = c.Name }).ToString());
            }

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I was told that I could then use this extension method in my Views (right now, I'm using _layout.cshtml) by using the @Html keyword, like so:

```
@Html.MyMenu //doesn't appears to be in the available method selection.
```

What's the reason why I can't call this method like that? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am not sure about `ASP.NET MVC`, but in general C# code, you need to import `MvcApplication1.HelperMethods` namespace for this method to be available. Is there any way you can import a namespace to `CSHTML` file?

Comment: @decyclone: Yeah that was the solution. I used: @using MvcApplication1.HelperMethods;

Answer (score 5):

Update you web.config:

```
  <system.web>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        ...
        <add namespace="MvcApplication1.HelperMethods" /><!-- Add this line -->
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
```

This way you won't need to use the using directive for MvcApplicatin1.HelperMethods in each View. And you can put multiple helper classes in that namespace.

Comment: This will allow me to use the extension methods without the 'using' import. +1 Thanks for sharing.

Comment: This applies to web.config file in Views folder

Answer (score 1):

Add a `using` clause for `MvcApplication1.HelperMethods`

Comment: Aha! Learn something new every day. Thanks a lot for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Wihtout seeing your view code it is hard to say exactly but you are probably missing a reference to MvcApplication1.HelperMethods in the view code.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the `@`, `Html` should do just fine (though `@Html` should work as well). You'd need to actually invoke the method, though:

```
Html.MyMenu()
```

And if you haven't got a program like ReSharper that'll suggest this for you, you need to include a reference to that namespace

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MvcApplication1.HelperMethods" %>
```